# I cannot import from one app to another . why cant I do it?

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

This is my directory :
[image]

I want to import The groups class model in group directory from here :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.urls import reverse
import misaka

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User=get_user_model()

from django import template
register = template.Library()

# GROUPS MODULES.PY.

class Group(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    slug= models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default= 'NOT_PROVIDED')
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False,default='', blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,through='GroupMember')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.description_html = misaka.html(self.description)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

and place it here in the posts/ models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
import misaka
from groups import Groups

#POST MODULES.PY

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message= models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts', null=True , blank=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = {'-created_at'}
        unique_together = ['user','message']
```

on Pycharm in the import 'from groups import Group'
is underlined red. I have no idea why its not working.

also this is the settings :
[image: Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import for groups is probably incorrect, you need to reference the file name within the Group app. If this is django- it's likely 'models.py' ex)

```
from groups.models import Group
```